# Centering a division within a div element

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox within a container and need to center it within the main container.

Right now its being displayed on the left hand side.

html

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="inner container">
        <input id="id" type="checkbox" name="name1" value="name1">
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
.maincontainer{
    height:100px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean both the checkbox and middle container like this http://jsfiddle.net/UDPYw/

Comment: I need only the middle container to be centered..I figured out based on the response..thanks

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer that is correct then.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

this looks to be what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/pHUcC/

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="inner container">
        <input id="id" type="checkbox" name="name1" value="name1">
        </input>
    </div>
</div>

.maincontainer{
    height:100px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/m55cy/)

```
.maincontainer{
    height:100px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```